# Getting an avarage value from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoose model:

```
var juomaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    valikoima: String,
    img: String,
    views: {default: 0, type: Number},
    rating: [],
    ...

});
juomaSchema.methods.getAvarageRating = function() {
    if (this.rating.length !== 0) {
        var totalScore = 0;
        this.rating.forEach(function(drinkRating) {
            totalScore += drinkRating
        });
        return totalScore/this.rating.length;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

My problem is, that I need to sort a query by the avarage rating of the rating field.
I already have the method in the model, but I can't seem to use a function inside a sort query.

Here's my sort:

```
router.get("/oluet", function(req, res) {
var perPage = 20,
    page    = req.query.page,
    sortBy  = req.query.sort,
    asc     = req.query.asc;

var sort = {[sortBy] : asc};
console.log(sort);
if(req.xhr) {
    //Sanitazes input
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(req.query.search), "gi");
    Juoma.find({nimi: regex, tyyppi: "oluet"})
        .sort(sort)
        .limit(perPage)
        .skip(perPage * page)
        .exec(function(err, drinks) {
```

How would I do this? Making two fields: totalRating and timesRates, and doing some aggregation magic?

Comment: use aggregation with `**$avg`** operator in a project stage like this: `{$project: {avg: {$avg: "$rating"}}}` and then sort on `avg` field

Comment: After a bit of fiddling, it worked! Thanks Felix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Felix solved this in the comments with

```
{
    $project: {
        avg: {$avg: "$rating"}
    }
}
```